# Difference between 'analogous to' and 'similar to'

Tags: meaning, differences

I am having a hard time understanding the difference (if any) between 'analogous to' and 'similar to'. Take for instance these two sentences:

> High level cognition is performed in a way **analogous** to symbolic computation.

and

> High level cognition is performed in a way **similar** to symbolic computation.

Comment: Though a good reference might be hard to find in this instance, some evidence of (even unfruitful) relevant research is expected on ELU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a discussion of analogy and similarity (and other terms referring to alikeness [here at M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/analogy).  The gist is this:

**Similar** refers to things that are somewhat alike, and those characteristics that are alike are the same in a direct comparison.  For example, you might use "similar" to describe how a man had a remarkable likeness to his father.

**Analogous** refers to parallelism or correspondence.  For example, the heart is analogous to a pump, or an airplane's joystick is somewhat analogous to the reins on a horse.

Comment: In Chinese, **similar** function like 甲像乙, while **analogous** function like 甲相當於乙.